# linked list NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am getting `NullPointerException` and I don't know why.

```
LinkedList<Character>[][] list = new LinkedList[n][n];

for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
{
    for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++)
    {
                // Here is the problem
        list[j][m].add("" + (characterArray[j]));
    }
}
```

I want to add characters from an array to the list. When I run it it says `NullPointerException`. I don't know how to initialize the list.

Comment: Use the interface `List<Character>[][] = ....`

Comment: Could you post the declaration of characterArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you created an two dimensional array of LinkedList objects. But remember that the default value for objects in Java is null, so when the array is first created you have a 2 dimensional array of nulls. In the nested for loops you are trying to populate the linkedlist objects you think you have but you don't (Their value is null). So basically you say

```
null.add("" + (characterArray[j]));
```

obviously this creates a null pointer exception.

So the solution is to make the object (in this case make a new LinkedList object) before trying to add to it. Either by having a separate 2 nested for loops as follows:

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    for(int m = 0; m < n; m++)
    {
        list[j][m] = new LinkedList<Charater>();
    }
}
```

followed normally by your code for the nested loops.

Or you can just declare the object inside your nested for loops

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
{
    for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++)
    {
                // Here is the problem
        list[j][m] = new LinkedList<Charater>();
        list[j][m].add("" + (characterArray[j]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You made an array, but you failed to put any `LinkedList` objects into the array.  You need to assign a new `LinkedList` to `list[j][m]` before you go adding characters to it.

Comment: I don't want to put any other objects into the list except some characters from an array. I don't quite get it. How do you mean to initialize it?

Comment: A `LinkedList` is an object.  You have created an array with space for `n*n LinkedList` objects.  But you haven't created the `LinkedList` objects themselves.  You need to write something like `list[j][m] = new LinkedList<Character>();` inside your loop, because if you don't, there is no `LinkedList`, and you are trying to add characters to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks. Aand do you know how I can sort the 2d list as Collenctions.sort(list) does not work since its 2d array list [][]?

Comment: What kind of order do you want it in?

Comment: You do realise that you've actually got a 3D structure, right?